# Changing annotations in time series plots in R

Tags: r, annotations, plot, time-series

While I can change annotations with the generic plot command turning off axes and 
annotations and specifying them again using the axis command e.g.

```
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)

plot(cars, type="o", col="blue", ylim=range(0, cars), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)  
axis(1, at=1:5, lab=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"))
```

I cant do it with time series object e.g.

```
www <- "http://www.massey.ac.nz/~pscowper/ts/Maine.dat"  
Maine.month <- read.table(www, header = TRUE)  
attach(Maine.month)  
Maine.month.ts <- ts(unemploy, start = c(1996, 1), freq = 12)  
Maine.98 <- window(Maine.month.ts, start = c(1998,1), end = c(1998,11))
```

How can I plot `Maine.98` with annotations looking like:

```
"Jan-98"   "Feb-98"   "Mar-98"   "Apr-98"   "May-98"  etc?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the `ts` type for time series which is suitable for ARIMA-modeling and series with fixed 'delta t' such as monhtly or quarterly series.

But R is good at working with dates in general. Try experimenting with keeping your data in a `data.frame`, but convert your x-axis data to either type `Date` or `POSIXt`. The `plot()` will call an axis-formatting function that knows about time and you get better defaults which you can still override.

Better still is use of packages [**zoo**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) or [**xts**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) which give you additional control as well as bells and whistles:

```
 > X <- data.frame(x=seq(Sys.Date()-11*31,Sys.Date(),by="1 months"),  
                    y=cumsum(rnorm(12)))
 > plot(X)                   # plot as a data.frame with Date column
 > library(zoo)
 > plot(zoo(X[,-1], X[,1]))  # plot as a zoo object
 > library(xts)
 > plot(xts(X[,-1], X[,1]))  # plot as an xts object
```

*Edit:*  I forgot that if your data is already a `ts` object, you have easier converters
`as.zoo()` and `as.xts()`.  And the `plot.zoo` help page has examples for custom formatting of the time axis.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that "by" in "seq" accepts strings like "1 months". Where is that referenced in help? Apart from months, what other time intervals can be used?

Comment: In this case it is 'seq.Date' to which `seq` dispatches on `Date` class objects.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what Dirk said:

Once you're using a proper date type (Date or POSIXt), then you can use the format() command to choose how you want it to look in your plot:

```
> format(seq(Sys.Date()-11*31,Sys.Date(),by="1 months"), "%b-%y")
 [1] "Oct-08" "Nov-08" "Dec-08" "Jan-09" "Feb-09" "Mar-09" "Apr-09" "May-09"
 [9] "Jun-09" "Jul-09" "Aug-09" "Sep-09"
```

Look at the help for strptime for more examples of formatting options.

```
?strptime
```